# MySQL Horizontal Partition by Age

Tags: mysql, partitioning

In my MySQL database table only the most recent two weeks of records are used by our front end users. Any data older then this is only used by administration.

What I would like to do is optimize the performance for front end users by horizontally partitioning the database based on the age of the record in the database.

So the front end would need one of the partitions made that would only contain the past two weeks of records and another partition made to contain any record older then 2 weeks.

However, I did not see in the MySQL documentation ([here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html)) if this can or cannot be done.

Can someone please advise if this can be accomplished and how the table's create statement might look?

Comment: I'm not really sure to understand correctly your question. Can you provide a small set of mock data to clarify what you call "horizontal provisionning" ? Thanks.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this? I'm facing the same problem. Thanks

Answer (score -2):

ok, for a two-table solution, the union sql would look something like this:

admin users would use:

```
select
  id,
  column1,
  column2,
  age
from
  oldrecs

union

select
  id,
  column1,
  column2,
  age
from
  newrecs

order by
  age
```

This is a single query and will return a single result set. Note that select blocks have the same field count and type. In your case, both tables will have same layout.

Meanwhile your website users would only use last part of that query:

```
select
  id,
  column1,
  column2,
  age
from
  newrecs
order by
  age
```

Besides this, you'll need a cron job to move aged records from newrecs table to oldrecs table.

```
  insert into oldrecs
  select
    id,
    column1,
    column2,
    age
  from
    newrecs
  where
    age < date(now()) - interval 7 days;

  delete from
    newrecs
  where
    age < date(now()) - interval 7 days;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this does not do what I'm asking for. Instead this just separates a single table into 6 different partitions in a round robin fashion based on the month. What I'm looking for would actually need only two partitions, one that always has the last two weeks of records and one that has anything older then two weeks.

Comment: it was the example given in mysql documentation, I was assuming you'd tailor the example for your own situation.

however thinking of it, I see a problem. the system you suggest would require mysql to move data from first partition to second one, as records get older, every day. this I dont see happening.

you might want to consider using two tables, like newrecs and oldrecs, of same format, giving your normal users results from only newrec table, and giving your admin stuff results from oldrecs union newrecs. and then in a cron job, move records that got old that day to the other table.

Comment: That's along the lines I was thinking for a work around. However the admins will need to see items from both the new table and the old table and I'm not sure how to join separate tables together to add more rows and not more columns. I am wondering if there is a way to create two separate partitions and just manually move items from one partition to another using a cron job. That would do the same thing without a nasty join needed.

Comment: That is done with a union, like:

select id,afield,anotherfield from oldrecs
union
select id,afield,anotherfield from newrecs
order by date

Comment: let me know if you cant read it, so I put it into another answer with code blocks.

Comment: If you could reformat this answer to use two separate tables with the union statement as a workaround I would be happy to accept that as the answer for this question.